# Having trouble setting radio with additional state method in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Having trouble updating the radio value and also update a data object.  This code works fine to change radio value :

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState('cardio');
const handleRadioChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    setValue(value);
};
```

However, when I also try to use another method to set the value in the exercise object, it sets it there correctly but no longer changes the value of the radio group.

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState('cardio');
const handleRadioChange = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target
  setValue(value);
  setExercise({
      ...exercise, 
      [name]: value});
};

console.log(value);
console.log(exercise);
```

The console logs return what I expect:

```
body
{name: "", group: "cardio"}
```

Other relevant bits :

```
const defaultExercise = {
    name: '',
    group: ''
}
const [exercise, setExercise] = useState(defaultExercise);
```

and the form :

```
return (
  <FormControl component="fieldset">
    <FormLabel component="legend">Types</FormLabel>
    <RadioGroup aria-label="group" name="group" value={value} onChange={handleRadioChange} row>
      <FormControlLabel value="cardio" control={<Radio />} label="Cardio" />
      <FormControlLabel value="body" control={<Radio />} label="Body" />
      <FormControlLabel value="weights" control={<Radio />} label="Weights" />
    </RadioGroup>
  </FormControl>
);
```

Update : After discussing I think it is my structure causing the issue as that code above seems to work fine.  Here is a sandbox closer to what I really have and the error exists there :  https://codesandbox.io/s/having-trouble-setting-radio-with-additional-state-method-in-react-forked-qg5we?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you clarify what array is being set correctly? There isn't any referenced array from what I can see, in your snippet.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese.  I am not sure why I said array sorry to be confusing, I updated my question and tried to make it more clear.

Comment: Hi, I'm not able to reproduce the issue you describe here in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/having-trouble-setting-radio-with-additional-state-method-in-react-f2w4m) where I copy/pasted your code. Can you try creating a codesandbox that reproduces the issue that we can debug in live?

Comment: I also did the same but it's working as expected...

Comment: codesandbox is cool!  I did not know about that thanks.   Now that I am looking at what you have I think I see my problem is the weird way I nested these.. I was able to recreate in a sandbox  : https://codesandbox.io/s/having-trouble-setting-radio-with-additional-state-method-in-react-forked-qg5we?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Ah so it was just the way I had nested form controls.  I simplified it and now it works fine.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the given codesanbox demo, the issue is that you've declared the state inside another function in a component. The rule of react hooks is that **Only Call Hooks at the Top Level**.

The rule states that:- ***Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders.***

Check the [React hooks documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level) for refrecnce.

So in this issue just move your state of `value` to main `AddExercise` component.

Working [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/having-trouble-setting-radio-with-additional-state-method-in-react-forked-4j7eo) demo

```
export default function AddExercise(props) {
  const defaultExercise = {
    name: "",
    group: ""
  };
  const [exercise, setExercise] = useState(defaultExercise);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("cardio");

  function RadioButtonsGroup() {
    const handleRadioChange = (e) => {
      const { name, value } = e.target;
      setValue(value);
      setExercise({
        ...exercise,
        [name]: value
      });

      console.log(value);
      console.log(exercise);
    };
    return (
      <FormControl component="fieldset">
        <FormLabel component="legend">Types</FormLabel>
        <RadioGroup
          aria-label="group"
          name="group"
          value={value}
          onChange={handleRadioChange}
          row
        >
          <FormControlLabel
            name="group"
            value="cardio"
            control={<Radio />}
            label="Cardio"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            name="group"
            value="body"
            control={<Radio />}
            label="Body"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            name="group"
            value="weights"
            control={<Radio />}
            label="Weights"
          />
        </RadioGroup>
      </FormControl>
    );
  }

  return (
    <form noValidate onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
      <FormControl>
        <RadioButtonsGroup />
      </FormControl>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: HI, I just came to that conclusion as well.  Thank you for the explanation.. it all is helping me learn!

Comment: :) yp.. Speaking of learning, I feel learning should never stop!!